# Does UUID V5 provide a reasonable uniqueness assumption when transforming an existing set of unique ids?

Tags: uuid

I have a dataset with around 1 billion entities, each of which has an existing unique ID. As part of a migration I want to map these existing IDs into UUIDs deterministically using the UUID V5 schema.

I was thinking I could use one namespace for all items (although this isn't a necessity), and the already existing ID as the inputted Name.

```
newId := uuid.newV5(CONSTANT_NAMESPACE, existingID)
```

Doing the math for the probability of a collision with UUID V4 is pretty simple since its a bunch of random bits, but I don't know how to calculate the collision probability for UUID v5 in this scenario. Since this is a deterministic generation, I'm not sure if I can make the same randomness assumption.

Do I need to worry about having collisions with these new IDs?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to worry about collisions any more with V5 than you do with V4.

One of the properties of cryptographic hashes is that even *one* changed bit in the input has a (roughly) 50% chance of changing each bit in the output. This is needed in security applications to prevent reversing the hash, and UUID cleverly takes advantage of that to provide statistical collision resistance for both V4 and V5 despite relatively small amounts of input data.

This [Cryptography Stack Exchange question's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/hash-functions-and-the-avalanche-effect/40271#40271) provides additional details about this property (which is called the avalanche effect) and this other [question answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26754/does-sha-1-meet-the-strict-avalanche-criterion) provides details about  SHA-1 and the avalanche effect.